# Is it possible to generate a keyframe to start a spliced H.264 video segment?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, h.264

When segmenting files with `ffmpeg`, I am currently only able to splice on keyframe boundaries if I don't want to reencode. This presents issues if I want to control timing down to a specific frame. To my knowledge, you can only start on a keyframe if you're performing a stream copy. If you want to start on an arbitrary frame, you must reencode.

However, for codecs that `ffmpeg` understands (like H.264), it seems like it would be technically possible to replace the desired first frame with a newly created keyframe without reencoding the rest of the video. This would represent a "smart copy" sort of behavior. For example, say my video consists of these frames and types:

```
Frame number:  0         1         2         3
               0123456789012345678901234567890123
Frame type:    IppbppbppbppbIppbppbppbppbIppbppbp
Keyframes:     ^            ^            ^
```

(`I` frames are keyframes while `p` and `b` frames are not)

Currently, if I want to remove the first few frames and start on exactly frame 20, I must reencode the entire stream beginning with that input frame. This would cause an undesired degradation in quality. Instead, if I perform a copy, `ffmpeg` would begin at the most recent keyframe:

```
Frame number:  0         1         2         3
               0123456789012345678901234567890123
Frame type:    IppbppbppbppbIppbppbppbppbIppbppbp
Desired start:                     ^
Actual start:               ^
```

Why can't `ffmpeg` seek to frame 13 (the last complete keyframe prior to the cut point), fully calculate frame 20, and recreate frame 20 as an I frame? It would then copy the remaining frames as before. Like this:

```
Frame number:  0         1         2         3
               0123456789012345678901234567890123
Input type:    IppbppbppbppbIppbppbppbppbIppbppbp
Output type:                       IpbppbIppbppbp
```

It seems like this would be a very useful feature for splicing videos without losing quality. Is there any technical barrier (e.g. the H.264 spec or any other common codec) that prevents this approach?

Answer (score 3):

Not only must it begin with a keyframe (IDR), it must also be closed GOP. In h.264 a P/B frames can reference up to 16 other frames. So if you replace the first frame, you must also replace all later frames that reference a frame before your new frame. In practice, this would be almost all frames. In addition, this process would really screw with the deblocking filter, as it will attempt to fix artifacts that may have been modified.

Comment: Okay, so it seems reasonable that you might replace all the `P` and `B` frames following the newly inserted `I` frame, up to the next `I` frame. But then, wouldn't the next `I` frame (frame 26 in my example) and all following frames be able to be copied as-is?

In other words, you'd have to create a new `I` frame to replace frame 20, then build new frames for 21-25, but after that you could copy as-is. Would that be possible?

Comment: Assuming it is closed GOP, it would probably work. But it may be difficult to find good places to do this if b frames are used as you are splitting a GOP into two GOPs.

Comment: My thinking: "ffmpeg -ss 1060 -i in.mp4 -c copy out2.mp4" will copy the rest of the video without reencoding, then "ffmpeg -ss 1000 -i in.mp4 -ss 42.3 -t 17.7 -c:a copy out1.mp4", then using "ffmpeg -f concat -i inlist -c copy out.mp4" will rejoin the two parts. Use ffprobe -show_frames -read_intervals A%B. Could be automated with a script.